# Sorting bibliography in chronological order [natbib]

Tags: bibtex

NOT using biblatex, I want my bibliography sorted in chronological order.

Why do I want that? Mainly because I think that way the bibliography not only serve as a "repository" for the references, but it also shows the progression of the literature on the topic.

I have searched the web, but mainly ended up with in-text sorting only, or not working modification of the bibtex style bst file.

Comment: How large is your bibliography: A few dozen entries, or several hundred? Separately, how are entries with the same year supposed to be sorted -- alphabetically by author, or by some other criterion?

Comment: ~hundred. for same-year entries, the inner sorting is less important, I left it to an alphabetical order (that's the role of `year.author.sort`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a small set of modifications for a bst file. I only tested it with author-year style, francaissc.bst.

Basically, the `presort` function must be altered.

Without entering in too much details about the bst files, there is one thing to understand for making those modifications: the .sort are functions, that must be defined, for example `author.editor.sort` is most likely already defined in an author-year style.

Hence, first thing to do is to add those functions:

```
FUNCTION {year.author.sort}
{ year empty$
    { author empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need year, author, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { author sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { year sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {year.sort}
{ year empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need year or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { year sort.format.names }
  if$
}
```

They are very simple because they rely on stuff already defined in there, mostly the `sort.format.names` function.

Then, you must modify the `presort` function itself. Basically, change `author` to `year`, but I let be the judge of what you actually want to change. In my case I now have (a commented line is the previous content, with the new one next line):

```
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
%    'author.editor.sort
     'year.author.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
%        'editor.sort
%        'author.sort
        'author.sort
        'year.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
%  title field.or.null
  year field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

And for an added bonus, with the 'sort' option of the natbib package, the in-text references are now also ordered chronologically, because the main bibliography is.

Answer (score 1):

The package `multibibliography` http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibibliography includes the creation of a chronlogically ordered reference list.  You probably can use just the Perl script to create the timeline reference list.

Right now Michael Cohen and I work on the refactored version of the package which will include a stand alone chronological `bst` file.

Comment: it there a way to change the sorting order of an existing bst? because most of the time 1) the style is imposed, 2) one will not be willing to create a full bst and make all the typographic choices.